# Taking database from possibly cracked server

Tags: mysql, database, hacking

I have a server which is behaving erratically. While I investigate if it's been hacked, I'm also thinking about my backup options:

As many posts have said the only way to truly know you're clean is wipe and start again.

Once I've reset the server I'd like to restore the website from backups.

The problem is I don't know when it was cracked (although I can take a guess).

If I restore a database from the cracked server is there a possibility that the database itself was somehow compromised or, assuming I've changed all the passwords etc., can I restore from that database?

My understanding is people attempt to steal from the database as opposed to using the database itself as an exploit, but I don't really know.

(In this case I think the server has been hijacked to send spam mail and there's not really very much of value in the database, small website, 5 users etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Known, Good Backups**

I assume you don't have existing backups from a point in time before the security incident?

If you do, you would want to restore to those and possible review what data has been added since, which could be non-trivial if a large number of records have been added to the database.

**Using Current Server's Data**

If you plan on using data from the compromised server, then it should not be trusted.

Dump the data to another system.  Change the mysql passwords as well as any passwords your applications store in the database.

Once this is complete, you can then re-import this to a known good server.

If your database stores HTML code or similar data, you may want to scan SQL dump files with malware tools for known injection codes.  This is not 100% reliable but I've been able to spot SQL injections this way using tools like maldet and clamav.

Comment: I do (weekly at home, daily with host), but the problem is I'm not 100% sure when the break happened, so I can't be sure. So the main suspect for a compromised database is SQL injection code in it? My worry is accidentally bringing across the attack window with the database. (I'll take changing all the passwords as a default)